# how to setup SDL libraries with atom editor?

Tags: c, sdl, atom-editor, sdl-2

So, I wanna develop pretty basic games with 2D graphics in `C`. Someone recommended me SDL so I downloaded `sdl 2.0` (from the `development libraries` link,  from their official site) but I don't know how to include the header files in my source code which I'm writing in `atom (editor)` because I don't want to use any IDE. Also, I use windows and not Linux.

I tried to include the file like this: `#include "C:\SDL2-devel-2.0.9-mingw\SDL2-2.0.9\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2\SDL.h"` but it showed this error: `undefined reference to WinMain'` . I changed the arguments of main also: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` but it didn't work.

I just want to normally include the file like others do: `#include <SDL2\SDL.h>` and work with SDL.

Am I supposed to copy paste all the .h files from SDL's include folder to the library folder of my compiler(`TDM-GCC-64`)?

Somewhere I read, that you have to use some sort of command line for adding third party libraries but I couldn't understand plus there's SDL and SDL2. And all the tutorials regarding this is about c++ and I'm hella confused. Is nobody learning C?

Comment: Initial setup should be the same for both C and C++ - SDL itself have nothing C++ specific. SDL 1.2 is "legacy" and shouldn't be used for new projects. Put headers into where your compiler stores them, or specify path to headers directory (e.g. `-Ipath/to/header/dir` for gcc), *and* link with SDL libraries. `undefined reference to WinMain` means you don't link with `SDL2main`. Where have you put your files and what's your resulting build command?

Comment: @keltar I tried to setup SDL in MinGW by [lazyfoo's](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php) tutorial which is pretty old and it also said "_most compilers still compile 32bit binaries by default to maximize compatibility. We will be using the 32bit binaries for this tutorial set. It doesn't matter if you have a 64bit operating system, since we are compiling 32bit binaries we will be using the 32bit library._" but I have `TMD-GCC-64` bit compiler. When I tried compile the .cpp file using command prompt it said cannot find `-lSDL2` and `-lSDL2main`.

Comment: You need to specify path to directory containing libraries with `-L/path/to/lib/dir` (similar to path to includes directory with `-I` flag). Once again, where your SDL files placed and what's your *full* resulting build command?

Comment: @keltar My SDL files are placed in `C:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2` and my final build command is`g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL`.

Comment: Also, currently I'm just trying to build the sample source code as given in the tutorial but later I have to work with C. Now what to do?

Comment: Looks fine, if you execute it in windows cmd (not bash) and you have correct libraries in `C:\mingw_dev_lib\lib`. What is the error message for that command? What is `TMD-GCC-64` exactly? Are your compiler produce 64bit binaries and you're using 64bit SDL2 libraries?

Comment: @keltar `TMD-GCC-64` is 64 bit MinGW compiler and it does compile my C programs. And yeah, I'm trying to use 64 bit SDL libraries (should I use 32 bit libraries?) The command gives these errors:   `skipping incompatible C:\mingw_dev_lib\lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main, cannot find -lSDL2main`, `skipping incompatible C:\mingw_dev_lib\lib/libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2` and `cannot find -lSDL2`. Final message: `error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: I don't know, never heard that name, and I'm using mingw quite a lot; but `skipping incompatible` means your compiler expects different archintecture. So, contrary to its name suggesting it is 64bit, it may actually be 32 - try 32bit libs.

Comment: @keltar I have these files in the lib folder: `libSDL2.a`, `libSDL2.dll.a`, `libSDL2.la`, `libSDL2_test.a`, `libSDL2_test.la`, `libSDL2main.a` and `libSDL2main.la`

Comment: @keltar the build code was for 32 bit libraries, I just did what the tutorial said but my compiler was 64 bit.

Comment: I don't see any `-m32` flag triggering 32bit mode. So if your supposedly-amd64 compiler complains about incompatible library when it sees supposedly-amd64 library - one of these things is very likely to be wrong.

Comment: @keltar I used -m32 with the build code(at the end of it), nothing happens. But then I used -m64 then the same errors show up. Also, sorry for wasting your time:(

Comment: Don't be sorry, I'm here voluntarily; if you managed to figure something out of it - it isn't wasted time. So is your problem solved? It isn't clear to me.

Comment: @keltar I'm starting to understand a little as to what and why I'm doing considering I'm completely new to this and I'm self learning but the same errors show up with -m64 and nothing happens with -m32.  I wrote these flags at the end of build code, is that okay?

Comment: What "nothing happens" mean? Did it compile (i.e. no error message, and you've got new executable `01_hello_SDL.exe`)? If so, then I suppose your library directory contains 32bit SDL2 (correctly refered to as "x86" or "i686" because there are many different architectures) and not amd64 as initially implied. You can get SDL development libraries at libsdl.org; amd64 libs are located in `x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` directory. You might also need dll in your executable directory to actually run resulting executable.

Comment: @keltar Nothing came up when I entered that code but then I checked the folder and had the .exe file there and I also copied the sdl.dll file to the same library. The exe file closed as soon as it was opened but there was a sample code in the source file. I don't know what is "x86" and "i686" but I think I had used library files from i686 smh. Okay, so do I have to just use files from "x86_64-w64-mingw32" and repeat the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but without `-m32`, so you'll produce executable for your compiler's default architecture (amd64 in your case, often refered to as "x86_64" or sometimes probably-not-correctly as "x64"). DLL should have correct architecture too, or you'll get runtime error on your executable's startup.

Comment: (That is, if you want to build 64 bit executable. If you're fine with 32 - just use `-m32` for both compiling and linking).

Comment: @keltar This time I used amd64 libs as you said from `x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` and used the build code without using the flag -m32(i.e for 64bit) and the exe file was created. But the final issue is that the file closes as soon as I open it and also I wanted to compile using `atom-editor` and not cmd.

Comment: Shouldn't it though? What's your code (you can edit your own question to include code if you think necessary, comments can't hold code)? Is there any output if you run it from the same cmd and not by clicking it windows explorer (type `01_hello_SDL.exe` or something like that)? I can't help you with atom part, sorry, there should be in its manual on how to integrate it with `make` though, and said lazyfoo tutorial describes a `Makefile`.

Comment: @keltar yeah, okay I'll do makefile. I now have an idea of what I'm trying to do and I can proceed further by myself. Thanks for your help man, you'll go to heaven:)